# How can I set the dash length in pyplot.hist?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, linestyle

I know the dashes length and gap size can be set in plt.plot but is there a way to do so in plt.hist? This is what my command looks like:
`plt.hist(x, bins=5, range=(7.,11.), facecolor='None', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, normed=1)`

Comment: Setting of line styles has been unified on master.

Answer (score 1):

Simply read up on the [official documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html):

[`set_dashes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_dashes) is a function that takes a sequence of on and off lengths in points.

So `set_dashes((3,3))` should produce something different then `set_dashes((15,15))`.

Now, for `hist` that won't really work, since setting the line properties, at best, will change the appearance of the outline.

What you can do instead is

1. use `numpy`'s `histogram` function; it's used by pyplot's `hist`, anyway, and then
2. plot the results using `stem`.

Comment: `set_dashes()` works with something like `lines, = plt.plot(x)` and then `lines.set_dashes(...)`. But the `hist` function does not allow to store the plot into a variable. Or does it?

Comment: @tcaswell: um, no. actually, using stem would give you the ability to plot lines instead of rectangles.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: not sure how to get `stem` to plot a histogram. Is that possible? I checked the documentation but got nothing.

Comment: a histogram is just a set of heights, right? so nothing a stem plot can't visualize.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer pointed out the set_dashes method does not work for histograms. However, you can achieve fine control over the linestyle by passing a dash tuple directly to "linestyle" (see the documentation here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html)

In your example, you could achieve the "loosely dashed" style in the link as follows

```
x=[7]*10
plt.hist(x, bins=5, range=(7.,11.), ec='k', facecolor='None', 
         linewidth=2, normed=1, linestyle=(0,(5,10)))
```

This works for me with matplotlib 3.0.3. Note I also, had to add `ec='k'` to get the outline of the histogram to appear at all...